# How do I use custom deserialization on gson for generic type?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

For standard POJO, we can use the following

```java
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType2.class, new MyTypeAdapter());
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, new MySerializer());
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, new MyDeserializer());
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyType.class, new MyInstanceCreator());
```

How about if the POJO is generic? The [Gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) doesn't mention it. Below is my code but it's not the correct one.

```java
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CustomResponse<POJOA>.getClass(), new POJOADeserializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CustomResponse<POJOB>.getClass(), new POJOBDeserializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CustomResponse<POJOC>.getClass(), new POJOCDeserializer());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CustomResponse<POJOA>.getClass(), new POJOADeserializer());
```

Register your deserializer like so:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(
        new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOA>>(){}.getType(), new POJOADeserializer());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please take a look at my `CustomRequest` class. I am able to print the json from `Log.d("CustomRequest", json);`. That means I get the data, but I didn't get anything from `return (Response<T>) Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));`. what's wrong?

Comment: I think I'll start new question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873650/why-does-my-gsonrequest-return-nothing-on-parsenetworkresponse