# How do I put generic type for Gson's TypeToken?

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

**EDIT** After experimenting for a while, I know my problem is. I can't put generic type inside `TypeToken` (`Type type = new TypeToken<CustomResponse<T>>(){}.getType();`). When I change `T` into `POJOA`, I can run my app just fine to deserialize json into `POJOA`, but not into `POJOB` and `POJOC`.

How do I put generic type into TypeToken? Or, is it possible to do something like this:

```
if (T == POJOA) {
  Type type = new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOA>>(){}.getType();
} else if (T == POJOB) {
  Type type = new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOB>>(){}.getType();
} else if (T == POJOC) {
  Type type = new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOC>>(){}.getType();
};
```

**Previous Question: Why do `parseNetworkResponse` return nothing when using parametrized type?**

I suspect the error is in `return (Response<T>) Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));` part, because it could print `Log.d("CustomRequest", json);` on previous line. (please look at **My GsonRequest**)

**My POJO**

```
public class CustomResponse<T> {
  T response;

  public CustomResponse(T response) {
    this.response = response;
  }

  public T getResponse() {
    return response;
  }
}
```

**My custom deserializer**

```
public class POJOADeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CustomResponse<POJOA>> {

    @Override
    public CustomResponse<POJOA> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        //some deserializing thing

        return new CustomResponse<POJOA>();
    }
}

public class POJOBDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CustomResponse<POJOB>> {

    @Override
    public CustomResponse<POJOB> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        //some deserializing thing

        return new CustomResponse<POJOB>();
    }
}

public class POJOCDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CustomResponse<POJOC>> {

    @Override
    public CustomResponse<POJOC> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        //some deserializing thing

        return new CustomResponse<POJOC>();
    }
}
```

**My GsonRequest**

```
public class CustomRequest<T> extends JsonRequest<T> {

    private final Gson gson;
    private final Type typeOfT
    private final Response.Listener<T> listener;

    public CustomRequest(int method,
                         String url,
                         Type typeOfT,
                         JSONObject params,
                         Response.Listener<T> listener,
                         Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(method, url, params.toString(), listener, errorListener);
        this.typeOfT = typeOfT;
        this.listener = listener;

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOA>>(){}.getType(), new POJOADeserializer());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOB>>(){}.getType(), new POJOBDeserializer());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOC>>(){}.getType(), new POJOCDeserializer());
        this.gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    }

        @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            Log.d("CustomRequest", json);

            return (Response<T>) Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

**The actual calling**

```
public <T> void get(String url,
                    Response.Listener<CustomResponse<T>> listener,
                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

  Type type = new TypeToken<CustomResponse<T>>(){}.getType();
  CustomRequest<CustomResponse<T>> request = new CustomRequest<>(Request.Method.GET, url, type, null, listener, errorListener);
  Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext()).add(request);
}


public void getResponse() {
  String url = //some url;

  get(url, new Response.Listener<CustomResponse<POJOA>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(CustomResponse<POJOA> response) {
      //do something
    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      //do something
    }
  });
}
```

I can print `Log.d("CustomRequest", json);`

so that means I get the json response just fine.

The problem is `return (Response<T>) Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));`.

Is it error when casting to `(Response<T>)`.

Or is it error on `gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT)`

Comment: If you can see the json text but fail deserialization here Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, typeOfT) then it is very likely there is mismatch between the expected type and the real type of the json. I use Volley and I find Google's tutorial for making custom GsonRequest to be very confusing. So I just send a StringRequest whose String response I can parse with gson.fromJson without all the complexity.

Comment: yes, right now I retrieve it using `JsonObjectRequest` and then parse it into appropiate POJO using `gson` and then give it to the caller. It works fine. I just try to use `GsonRequest` so that I don't need to do two tasks (retrieve json and parse into POJO).

It seems we need explicitly declare something inside `TypeToken` because when I use `new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOA>>`, it works, but when I move it to a generic method, and use `new TypeToken<CustomResponse<T>>` inside it, it doesn't works.

Comment: Now it seems I now my problem. I should explicitly declare T in `new TypeToken<CustomResponse<T>>(){}.getType();`. When I change `T` into `POJOA`, I can run my app just fine. The problem is I can't parse it for `POJOB` and `POJOC`. I need to rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the `Type` explicitly. There's [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java, which basically means that at runtime all instances of `T` are replaced with `Object`.

You should either write three different deserializers for different response types(`POJOA`, `POJOB`, `POJOC`) or write a generic one. Something like this should work:

```
public class GenericConverter implements JsonDeserializer<CustomResponse<?>> {
    private Type typeOfResponse;

    public GenericConverter(Type typeOfResponse) {
        this.typeOfResponse = typeOfResponse;
    }

    public CustomResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
        CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse();
        response.setResponse(ctx.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("response"), typeOfResponse));
        return response;
    }
}
```

And register it appropriately:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOA>>(){}.getType(),
        new GenericConverter(POJOA.class));
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOB>>(){}.getType(),
        new GenericConverter(POJOB.class));
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<CustomResponse<POJOC>>(){}.getType(),
        new GenericConverter(POJOC.class));
```